# GIS Workorder System

Tags: postgresql, database-design

First off, these questions are relevant:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7900/pros-and-cons-of-having-one-table-per-entity-vs-having-a-shared-table-with-an-e/7907#7907

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55951/deciding-when-to-extend-to-child-tables

I'm quite new to database administration so I'm looking for some advice on how to set up a geographic workorder system. Specifically, I have several tables, each with a geographic feature type.

A workorder will consist of a description, date, etc, a feature type, and may be related to one or many features of one type. Each feature may be in many workorders, so I realize this is a many-to-many relationship, which confuses me even more.

Ultimately this data will be used in a python based ORM (SQLAlchemy). Flask will handle the creating and modification of the workorders. A mapping server will be accessing the data also, to map the workorders to their related features geometry.

The features are created in an Esri geodatabase and dumped into PostgreSQL regularly (using ogr2ogr).

Here is what I've come up with so far:

- Table Feature x - Each table of features with feature info and geometry
- Table workorder - holds the workorder info, date, description...
- Table workorder_feature - holds the workorder_id and feature_id

Workorder will have one to many relationship with Workorder_Feature, and since the Feature tables are getting droppped/recreated regularly I'll just have to recreate views that join the feature to their relevant workorder.

Another option I thought about was to have a table of workorders for each feature. But this doesn't seem like the best way to solve this though, if anyone has any alternatives I'd love to hear them.